# Is this an adverbial complement? "They led me _to believe that there was no danger_."

Tags: grammar, complements, adverbials

I'm a novice who realised the existence of this site today. The following picture is from *Idiomatic and Syntactic English Dictionary* by A.S. Hornby:

[image]

> #### Pattern 10
>
> Verbs marked P 10 may be followed by an object and an adverb or an adverb phrase (including adverbial infinitives meaning *in order to*....). See also the notes on the adverbial participles abive.
>
> Examples [...]
>
> 9. *They led* | *me* | ***to believe that there was no danger.***

I'm not sure whether the blue-coloured part, 'to believe that there was no danger', is an adverbial complement postmodifying 'led' according to the dictionary. If I had not seen the pattern 10, I would suppose the infinitive phrase is an adjectival complement postmodifying 'me'.

---

I know that the infinitive phrase is a complement which is obligatory, not a modifier. I also learnt the term 'a catenative complement'. But I'm not content with that term alone. I really want to know whether an infinitive complement is used as adjectival or adverbial or nominal. It's out of curiosity which is something I have been doing for my own understanding.

As you know, 'here' as in [Put it here] is an adverbial complement, not an adverbial modifier. I was told that 'you to go' as in [I want you to go] is a nominal complement clause (S+V+'O') and that 'to do it' as in [I asked you to do it] is also nominal (S+V+I,O+'D.O'). But, I'm not being sure of whether 'to believe that there was no danger' is also nominal or adjectival or adverbial which is an objective complement.

Comment: No, it's not an adverbial or adjectival modifier but a catenative complement of "led".

Comment: The fact that "Etc." appears in the heading indicates that it's not to be taken seriously. This is a list of heuristics, not a useful grammatical pattern.

Comment: It might help to clarify why you're concerned with classifying complements as adverbial, nominal or adjectival. Do you need to follow a specific school of thought for tests, or is this something you are doing for your own understanding? The book you cite seems to use a very broad category of "adverbial" that might not be particularly useful for understanding.

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English, thanking for your edited revision and taking care of me. It's out of curiosity which is something I have been doing for my own understanding. I also learnt the term 'a catenative complement'. But I'm not content with that term alone. I really want to know whether an infinitive complement is used as adjectival or adverbial or nominal.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not an adverbial complement.

The sentence pattern is indeed S-V-O. The subject and verb are obvious. The direct object is the entire clause following, *me to believe that there was no danger.*

This type of clause is known as an infinitive clause. It consists of a subject, *me* in this case, and an infinitive or an infinitive phrase (the latter is the case here; the object if the infinitive is the indirect quote *that there was no danger*).

I hope that this clears everything up, though I fear that a long comment chain may spring into existence.